# Why should I collect all the collectible trading cards?

Tags: deadly-premonition

All around town I've been picking up little scraps of cardstock with a variety of pictures on them. These "trading cards" don't seem to have an obvious reason to exist. Here are just a few I've found:

- "Emily"
- "Willie"
- A "Shadow" and an "Armed Shadow"
- A "Turkey Sandwich"
- "Ushah" and "Ushah's Chips"
- "Gina's Sponge" (whatever that means)
- Many others

**What the heck are these for?** Do they serve an individual or collective purpose? Do people want them? Am I just supposed look in my pockets once in awhile and admire my vast collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cards do not have any in-game function, aside from providing some background information about people and things in Greenvale.

There is also an achievement that can be obtained when you find all 65 of them.

http://shshatteredmemories.com/greenvale/trading-cards

Answer (score 0):

There is a chain of side quests for Wesley the Gunsmith where you need to show him your collection of trading cards, giving you rewards as the collection expands.

Each quest requires you collect more cards, and give the following rewards:

- 8 cards: a trading card
- 16 cards: another trading card
- 32 cards: "Passion Red" suit (larger life gauge)
- 48 cards: "Dancing all Night" suit (larger stress gauge)
- 64 cards: light sabre weapon